# I installed git v2.5.1 from source and it has no 'pull' command

Tags: git

I'm trying to install, as user, an updated git on a Debian wheezy box, which ships with 1.7.10 by default. I cloned https://github.com/git/git into `$HOME/git-git` (so that `$HOME/git` was available for the installation) and followed the instructions in INSTALL.

The instructions in INSTALL said it should Just Work if I ran it as user, i.e. install it to ~/bin, but it didn't, so I specified the prefix manually.

Did I forget a step?

```
~/git-git/git$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev \
    autoconf asciidoc xmlto docbook2x
~/git-git/git$ git checkout v2.5.1  # This is with git 1.7.10
~/git-git/git$ make configure
~/git-git/git$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/git
~/git-git/git$ make all doc info
Time passes...
~/git-git/git$ make install
~/git-git/git$ git pull
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    shell
```

`$PATH` contains my `~/git/bin`. Perhaps something else needs to point to one of these dirs?

```
$ ls ~/git
bin  lib  libexec  share

$ which git
/home/<me>/git/bin/git
```

**Edited** - I did do `make install`; I accidentally overlooked it while going through my history.

**Edited 2** - It works if I set `GIT_EXEC_PATH`. Why do I need to set this? The INSTALL file mentions that I can use it if I want to use git without installing; but I did install. Shouldn't this set things correctly?

```
$ export GIT_EXEC_PATH=$HOME/git/libexec/git-core
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: I think you forgot to "make install". You'll also have to put $HOME/git/bin in your PATH.

Comment: @Borealid good spot. I did do make install, and yeah, I have the right bin dir in my path. `$ which git  # /home/{me}/git/bin/git`